# btn-group-justified text wrapping

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a project I am working on where I need to have a few buttons, easy, but I want it to look good, not so easy, apparently.

I am using bootstrap, to allow for nice RWD. I am trying to use .btn-group-justified. The problem is that some of the buttons have a significant amount of text, this cannot be changed as the content has been provided to me. So, the text overflows into the next button, rather than just wrapping to a second line of text, thus making the button twice as tall, ish.

currently my code is

HTML

---

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="S1A.php" class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ghost-button">Check the newspaper classifieds for affordable
       pieces</button></a>
    <a href="S1B.php" class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ghost-button">Check for garage sales within walking distance</button></a>
    <a href="S1C.php" class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ghost-button">Do nothing</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
So, my question is, is there anything that I can do to cause the text to wrap within the button,? Eventually the screen size is small enough that I use media queries to make them block buttons, but I want to be able to use the button group as much as I can.

Comment: would you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: I would love to, but I tried, and I'm not quite sure how?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/k2e78jLL/2/

Comment: Kind of, what I really want is something like this: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3923223/3643150/71b8ae58-10ce-11e4-9b1b-468b7a0ef180.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k2e78jLL/5/

Comment: Is there a way to shrink the button width, and keep them all inline and just have the text inside of the button go to a second line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141477/discussion-between-diego-rios-and-lordbug).

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/k2e78jLL/6/

Comment: @Lordbug I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to override `white-space` for the buttons:

```css
button.btn {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
a.btn-group{
 height: 100%;
}

.btn-group{
 display: table;
 height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="S1A.php" class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ghost-button">Check the newspaper classifieds for affordable pieces</button></a>
    <a href="S1B.php" class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ghost-button">Check for garage sales within walking distance</button></a>
    <a href="S1C.php" class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ghost-button">Do nothing</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

After the reading the discussion you had with another member, I adjusted the css so that the buttons occupy 100% of the height as desired.